# Check if a dom attribute is used by the browser with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a dom attribute is used / not ignored by the browser.

For example the attribute allow="payment" with an iframe is working with chrome but ignored with firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Permissions-Policy

Is there's a way to achieve that with js ?

Thanks

Comment: The link you give shows Permissions-Policy: <directive> <allowlist>

Comment: just read the page :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Permissions-Policy#combining_http_header_and_iframe_policies